SharePoint Online Library - When a new Doc Set is created, only the creator should have permissions
I have a SharePoint Online Library which requires users to create a new doc set, which triggers flows for approvals, etc.  I just modified the Library Permissions to Stop Inheriting Permissions, but when I create new doc sets, each one still has the same users with permissions.  Can I set the Library up so that when a ne3w Doc Set is created, only the Created By user can Edit?  I'm then going to use one of my flows to grant permissions to the Approvers, and such.  Just wondering if this can be done without having 3 HTTP Request actions in Power Automate just to remove permissions.
Thanks!

You have to grant permissions using power automate only.

You can use "send a HTTP request" action to grant permission. Take a reference to this article: https://netwoven.com/sharepoint-custom-development/set-item-level-permission-in-sharepoint-list-using-power-automate/.
